# How to configure AsciiDoc copy to clipboard?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

How do I configure my AsciiDoc README.adoc project documentation code blocks/snippets to allow copy to clipboard? I want to add typical project README documentation using Gradle and AsciiDoc (README.adoc) to my project. My issue is when my documentation is rendered as HTML and I have a code block the code is syntax highlighted but I also want the copy to clipboard option. I am using Gradle and IntelliJ. See example README.adoc below.

```
= My Title
:source-highlighter: rouge

Example main:

[source,java]
----
public class Foo() {
    public static main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello AsciiDoc");
    }
}
----
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add some custom CSS and JavaScript to your HTML to make that work.

The JavaScript would run in the browser, locate all of the source blocks on the page, and then dynamically generate the DOM structures for the button, plus the events to make the copy to clipboard happen. The CSS would position and style the button.

Custom CSS and/or JavaScript can be added to `asciidoctor`-generated HTML using [docinfo files](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor/latest/docinfo/).

[clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) makes it easy to implement the copy functionality.

This has been a [feature request](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-extensions-lab/issues/61) for some time. There is potentially-working solution included in the discussion, but I have not tested it.